# Itemize in the mdframe

Tags: itemize, mdframed

I want put a dialogue in a mdframed environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{dwf}
{
    \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=0.5pt,
    linecolor=black,
    roundcorner=0pt,
    frametitlerule=false,
    frametitle={}
    ]
}
{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

See the following dialogue.
\begin{dwf}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[Teacher A:] How looks this sentence?
        \item[Teacher B:] Oh. Your name is crossed by the frame line.
        \item[Teacher A:] Yours Too.
    \end{itemize}
\end{dwf}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

What shall I do?

PS: I'm using XeLaTeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the `enumitem` package and use `align=left`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}    
\newenvironment{dwf}
{
    \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=0.5pt,
    linecolor=black,
    roundcorner=0pt,
    frametitlerule=false,
    frametitle={}
    ]
}
{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

See the following dialogue.
\begin{dwf}
    \begin{itemize}[align=left]
        \item[Teacher A:] How looks this sentence?
        \item[Teacher B:] Oh. Your name is crossed by the frame line.
        \item[Teacher A:] Yours Too.
    \end{itemize}
\end{dwf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to marmot. My problem is resolved by the help of this answer!